# Terminated due to Timeout error in Finding perfect square within a range c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to solve Sherlock and Square problem in Hackerrank [(link)](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-squares/problem) for finding the perfect square within a range of data. 4 test cases passed but i am getting a timeout error for large numbers. Please suggest something to improve its performance

My code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int squares(int a, int b) {
    long double i;
    long long int count=0;
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        long double b = sqrt(i);
        if(fmod(b,1)==0.000000)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int q,i,a,b;
    cin>>q;
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
        int result = squares(a, b);
        cout<<result<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "runtime error"? Is HackerRank giving you a timeout? Are you getting a segfault?

Comment: Hackerrank is giving terminated due to timeout error for some test cases. Although 4 test cases were successfully passed.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer without defeating the purpose of HackerRank. The whole point of the exercise is to come up with an efficient way of solving that problem. "You need to tackle this from a different angle" is not exactly helpfull.

Comment: A good first step would be to not use floating point numbers.

Comment: Is the sqrt function causing the timeout error? What is the alternative for it?

Comment: @ManishUpadhyaya Your algorithm is causing the error. Checking for every number in the range every time is fundamentally inefficient. You need to move away from a O(N) solution to a O(logN) or better if you want any chance of this being fast.

Comment: Figure out what the roots are for [4,16], [25,49], and [4,49] and see if you find a pattern.

Comment: Unless my brain already left me for the day, there's an O(1) solution.

Comment: Try and find a different way to do your looping  so you don't need to call square root all the time. Think about 2 consecutive values in your loop. If the first one isn't a perfect square, why wouldn't the next one be a perfect square?

Comment: Please post your complete question, since the link may expire in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Your speed issue is visible, with over 16 seconds runs, for big inputs such as

```
1
1 1000000000
```

So the trivial solution is to get rid of the loop in `squares()`, and calculate it
analytically:

```
int squares(int a, int b) 
{
    auto sqrt_from = a < 0 ? 0 : static_cast<int>(std::ceil(std::sqrt(a)));
    auto sqrt_to = b < 0 ? 0 : static_cast<int>(std::floor(std::sqrt(b)));
    return std::max(sqrt_to - sqrt_from + 1, 0);
}
```

Of course, if you block negative values at the input, then everything can be
made `unsigned` and you'd gain another bit:

```
unsigned squares(unsigned a, unsigned b) 
{
    auto sqrt_from = static_cast<unsigned >(std::ceil(std::sqrt(a)));
    auto sqrt_to =   static_cast<unsigned >(std::floor(std::sqrt(b)));
    return std::max(sqrt_to - sqrt_from + 1, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I realize there is a shortcut. As soon you find the first perfect square, eg. number 4 = 2 * 2, the next perfect square after 4 would be 9 = 3 * 3, and so on. Here is my code in Java.

```
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        int sq = (int) Math.sqrt(i);
        if (i == sq * sq) {
            count++;
            i = (sq + 1) * (sq + 1) - 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the square of the number *a* is the number of squares between 1 and *a*. For example *a=9* then Math.square(9)=3 (1, 4 and 9). The same way with *b*.

Here is my code:

```
int result=0;
double sqrt_b=Math.sqrt(b);
double sqrt_a=Math.sqrt(a);
int int_sqrt_a=(int)sqrt_a;
if(sqrt_a-int_sqrt_a==0) {
    sqrt_a=sqrt_a-1;
}
result=(int)((int)sqrt_b-(int)sqrt_a);
```